# learning to make sense of the syntax of syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax

i want to use `alter table`

but the syntax posted here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

is very confusing

i do not understand what the `[ ]` mean or the `{ }` mean or the pipes

is there some kind of tutorial that can help me understand this?

Comment: +1 The mysql documentation is confusing for beginners. I've even had trouble with it in the past, and I've used mysql since 3.22

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- The brackets `[ ]` denote optional expressions
- The pipes mean *OR*.
- The braces `{ }` group words for the pipes.

For example:

- `[COLUMN]` means that the word `COLUMN` can *optionally* appear
- `{INDEX|KEY}` means that either `INDEX` or `KEY` *must* appear
- `[FIRST | AFTER col_name ]` means that the word `FIRST` or `AFTER (the name of a column)` can *optionally* appear

Comment: @zerkms: I don't think it's necessarily a standard convention; the developers of MySQL could have made it up. I don't know for sure, though.

Comment: it's a very close relative or derivation of EBNF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

Answer (score 6):

`[]` means, that argument inside is optional
`{a|b}` means that you have to choose whether `a` or `b`

**UPD**: specifically for mysql you should look over here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/manual-conventions.html

Answer (score 4):

Example of an alter table statement to add a column to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN columnname INT
```

changing a column's name:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE COLUMN columnname newname INT
```

rename table:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME newname
```

drop a field from a table

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP columname
```

On the syntax side, the user @SLaks has a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Oh well. It's the full reference and I think for starting it's really an overkill.
Maybe you should try more simple and informal guides on the topic, like
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp or
http://infogoal.com/sql/sql-alter-table.htm etc. etc. If you get a book covering basic SQL stuff I'm quite sure that you'll find a nice explanation, too. If you understand the basics, you can go with the more complicated stuff in the reference (if you need it).